# How do you put space between two objects in the same row

Tags: html, css

I want to make a replica of the google homepage for a homework task, and I can't seem to format the two buttons (Google Search and I'm Feeling Lucky) below. My expected result:
[image: Expected results]

Actual results:
[image: Actual results]

I tried margins and other stuff but nothing seems to work. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- This link tag is used to link html file with css file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="center">
        <center>
            <br>
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google" width="272" height="92" class="Logo">
            <br>
            <br>
            <form action="https://google.com/search">
                <div class="box">
                    <input maxlength="2048" name="q" type="text" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autofocus role="combobox" spellcheck="false" class="center input">
                    <input type="submit" value="Google Search" hidden>
                </div>
                <section>
                    <div>
                        
                        <button type="submit" class="button">Google Search</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="button">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </form>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
```

SCSS:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: "Product Sans";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local("Open Sans"), local("OpenSans"),
        url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/productsans/v5/HYvgU2fE2nRJvZ5JFAumwegdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2)
            format("woff2");
}

body {
    font-family: Product Sans;
    height: 69.25vh;
}

.center {
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

section{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 23%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    align-items: center;
}

.box {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.box .input {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 13px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 89.8%;
    transition: box-shadow 100ms;
    outline: none;
}

.input:hover {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
        0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
        0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
        0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.button {
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 128px;
    height: 36px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.button:hover {
    border: 2px solid #DADCE0;

    // box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
    //  0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
    //  0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
    //  0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
// 255px x 72px
```

Sorry for asking such a stupid question, but I'm still learning this.

Comment: why have you unaccepted my answer after almost 5 months and accepted another one if my answer contains valuable information and one of my recommendations was the same as in the example of another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can research about a [gap property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) that adds space between flex and grid elements. It will suit you too instead of `br` tags to add vertical space between the image, the form and the set of buttons.

I do not recommend to use padding for this purpose since this property is for inner spacing of an element, between its content and border. Read more about [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#what_is_the_css_box_model).

The very common property for spacing between elements is margin. It works not only between flex and grid elements.

I also recommend you to use Developer Tools in Chrome and Firefox browsers to see a clear picture what you are actually getting in browsers and why.

Answer (score 2):

You can use property `column-gap` on the section tag to give spaces between flex items, you can learn more about it in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap). Like this

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
       <div>
        <button>Tes</button>
        <button>Test2</button>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.button` class, add a `padding-right` of desired spacing.
For example, `padding-right: 20px`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Rita Goel, unfortunately the padding right padded the tex not the objects as I wanted, but it allowed me realise that I could use margin-right or left (something like that) to do it. I will research more into margins (maybe my sass watch command broke while I tried out margins last time). Thanks for all your support and help! :) Have a nice day